# IDLE and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

if I enter this code in Ipython notebook it works:

```
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

but if enter it in python IDLE then I get this error:

```
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x0000000007957908>
```

Do you have any idea why?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's not an error, that's the returned value (here a reference to the object created) of your call to the function. Have you tried to call `plt.show()` after this line?

Answer (score 9):

When you work with IPython in the pylab mode, drawing is automatic after you plot something with matplotlib. This is not the case when you work in idle where you have to `plt.show` your image:

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> x = [1,3,6,2]
>>> y = [4,6,7,8]
>>> plt.scatter(x,y)
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x0000000005A6B7B8>
>>> plt.show()
```

If you want to plot automatically with idle you can use the interactive mode:

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> from matplotlib import interactive
>>> interactive(True)
>>> x = [1,3,6,2]
>>> y = [4,6,7,8]
>>> plt.scatter(x,y)
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x0000000005D11BA8>
(the figure is drawn)
```

Comment: how do you know what the user is trying to do?

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi, well, it is reasonable to think that if you use matplotlib to make a scatterplot, what you want is to see a plot. In IPython drawing is automatic, in idle you need to show it. So I suspect this is what is intriguing the OP when he says that in IPython **works** but it doesnt works in idle.

Answer (score 0):

**One answer: Read the docs properly**

That isn't an error, its just telling you what `plt.scatter(x,y)` returned... it basically means that the result of `plt.scatter(x,y)` is a `<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x0000000007957908>`

try this:

```
result = plt.scatter(x,y)
```

and do whatever you want with the `result`. If you wan't to learn to use the result object, read the docs properly. and if you still don't understand take a step back, do `dir(result)` and try something with each variable, function and class you come across..